# Class-cast Exception when passing an ArrayList-object between two Activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, classcastexception

I am trying to send an ArrayListobject from Activity A to Activity B but when I am trying to start Activity B a Class-Exception is Thrown

here is my Syntax for sending and receiving. The question is - how could I cast from object[] to string[]?

Or if its not possible - any other solutions?

ACTIVITY A

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CalculationsActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("strObj2D", stringObjects2D);
startActivity(intent);
```

activity B

```
private ArrayList <String[][]> stringObjects2D = new ArrayList <String[][]> () ; 
stringObjects2D = (ArrayList<String[][]>) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("strObj2D");

// the size of the arraylist is printed before the crash - so the data seems to be   there, that is 3 2D-arrays. 
System.out.println("size = " + stringObjects2D.size());

// its here the crash comes, trying to get the second listitem in the arraylist
String[] string =  (String[]) stringObjects2D.get(0)[1];
```

logccat

```
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.example.celestialnavigationii/com.example.celestialnavigationii.Calculati     onsActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[][]
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[][]
 08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):    at com.example.celestialnavigationii.CalculationsActivity.onCreate(CalculationsActivity.java:34)
08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
  08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
  08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
  08-04 22:00:16.290: E/AndroidRuntime(9458):   ... 11 more
```

*EDIT: and if I change the to getParcelableExtra I get a NullPointerException instead*

Comment: You need to use GetParcelableArrayListExtra, not GetParcelableExtra.

Comment: if I try it cannot cast to String[][] from parcelable, so called Bound Missmatch

Answer (score 0):

Put extra information with putStringArrayListExtra method on Acitvity A and retrieve with getStringArrayListExtra method on Activity B.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("strObj2D")` instead of `getIntent().getParcelableExtra("strObj2D")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `ArrayList <String[][]>` as `Serializable` . `ArrayList` implements `Serializable` so you can just use `putExtra(...)` method . And you should just recieve it like this

`ArrayList<String[][]> list = (ArrayList<String[][]>) getSerializableExtra("strObj2D");`

Comment: how do I pass it as Serializable?

Comment: using the code you provided `intent.putExtra("strObj2D", stringObjects2D); `